# Exporting EPA SWMM Model to QGIS

Tags: qgis, swmm

I want to transfer a SWMM Model to QGIS, the Subcatchments included.

I have tried:

- Exporting the map as a .dxf File from SWMM and importing the file again in QGIS.
  This only transfers the Nodes and the Links, not the Subcatchment Areas.
- Installing the ImportEpaNetImpFiles extension in QGIS and importing the .inp file directly.
  This leads to to Python Errors:

```
2021-03-30T14:11:41     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Johann/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ImportEpanetInpFiles\main.py", line 131, in run
  epa2gis(filePath[0], self.epsg_crs)
  File "C:/Users/Johann/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ImportEpanetInpFiles\Epa2GIS.py", line 31, in epa2gis
  d.BinUpdateClass()
  File "C:/Users/Johann/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ImportEpanetInpFiles\readEpanetFile.py", line 13, in BinUpdateClass
  mm = getBinInfo()
  File "C:/Users/Johann/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ImportEpanetInpFiles\readEpanetFile.py", line 716, in getBinInfo
  nodeJunctionElevations.append(float(mm[1]))
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: '00180M01'
```

I am using QGIS 3.18 and EPA SWMM 5.1

I want to transfer the Subcatchemnt Data to be shown as areas in QGIS, so I could e.g. project the percentage of impervious area in a different color for each subcatchment. I am assuming there is a way to get the subcatchment data from swmm to polygon data in QGIS, to do this.
Is this possible?

Comment: The SWMM catchment areas are not necessarly georeferenced. SWMM does not handle GIS data really, but if the modeller produced such data with georeferenced infor when creating the model, there could be a chance to retrieve the data. You nee to look for the information under [Polygons] in the .inp files

Comment: The plugin ImportEpaNetImpFiles will not help you at all. Yoiu will need to build a gis layer out of a plain text file.

Comment: I have started an answer, @egan if you are interesting in this approach, let me know here so I can develop a bit more about the steps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and wrote a plugin for it:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/generate_swmm_inp/

This one should do the job

Comment: This takes shapefiles from QGIS to SWMM not the other way around.

Comment: it does both, just give it a try. see: https://github.com/Jannik-Schilling/generate_swmm_inp

Comment: Please update your answer and include the link to github there. Comments may not stay around. Even better if you could share a snippet of your code here.

Answer (score 0):

The way I know is not the best and most straight forward one, but it will work.

- Step 1:
  Retrieve the information under [Polygons] from the .inp file. This could be done by saving this part into a text file and then import the data as points. It should be something like this:

```
    [Polygons]
    ;;Subcatchment   X-Coord            Y-Coord           
    ;;-------------- ------------------ ------------------
    1                -1451.135          8608.095          
    1                -1451.135          8598.223          
    1                -533.070           8696.940          
    1                414.610            8183.613          
    1                365.252            6742.349          
    1                -809.477           6544.916          
    1                -1688.055          6989.141          
    1                -1451.135          8598.223          
    2                2230.997           9318.855          
    2                5162.883           6781.836          
    2                1727.542           4738.401          
    2                473.840            6041.461          
    2                1164.857           7966.436
```

- Step 2: Create lines from the poits and give it a proper order
- Step 3: Create polygons from the lines using the id for different geometries.